# HTML, BOOTSTRAP

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm using

```
<a href="#menu3" class="btn btn-info" role="button">Back</a>
```

to link a div id=menu3, but instead it only add #menu3 in the webpage title

```
file:///C:/2015Java10-Workspace/CASE-STUDY-CW/WebContent/index2.html#menu3
```

any idea on how can I link  with only using button?

I have a navbar that is currently working, but with button it doesn't work.

```
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                <li class="active"><a data-toggle="tab" href="#home">Home</a></li>
                <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#menu1">Report a Defect</a></li>
```

Comment: What do you mean by *call*?

Comment: Already edited it, sorry, i mean link, like I'm using ajax, so I want to load what's inside the div with id=menu3

Comment: If I understand it correctly, you want to get the content of the div#menu3 and display it.

Comment: Yeah, somewhat like that

Answer (score 0):

You need to set an anchor in the place you want to show.

```
<a name="menu3"></a>
```

Comment: Where? What I want is to by clicking the button, it will load the div with id=menu3. Is it possible?

Comment: Use jQuery to access specific html id.

Answer (score 0):

Hope this helps..

`<a href="#menu3" class="btn btn-info" role="button">Back</a>`

`<button onClick="location.href='index2.html#menu3'">`

Comment: but the location of my <div id=3> is also in index2.html, so it doesn't see the index2.html#menu3

Answer (score 0):

```
<A href="<%=request.getContextPath()%>" class="btn btn-info" id="menu3" role="button">Back</A>
```

Comment: Multiple annotations found at this line:
 - Invalid character used in text string (<%=request.getContextPath()%>" class="btn btn-info" id="menu3" 
  role="button">Back).
 - Start tag (<a>) not closed properly, expected '>'.

Answer (score 0):

in my code i can

```
 <button type="button" id="bt_XS" class="btn btn-default" data-toggle="collapse"data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="left" title="Logout"
                            data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
                            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                        </button>
```

in java script

```
$(function () {

    //test submit
    $( "#bt_XS" ).click(function() {

            window.open('<%=request.getContextPath()%>/LogoutServlet?logoutExitPage=logout.jsp','_self');


    });
```